# jfsutils install on CentOS plus

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machine

This is actually related to a previous question I'd deleted on here. I'm trying to install the jfs file system on one of my disk partitions, but it's telling me no such package exists. These are the steps I'm supposed to take:

```
wget http://elrepo.org/linux/elrepo/el5/i386/RPMS/elrepo-release-5-4.el5.elrepo.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh elrepo-release*rpm
yum install kmod-jfs
yum install jfsutils
```

Installing the modules worked fine, but the *yum install jfsutils* doesn't work. It says no jfsutils package exists.

My vm is running 32-bit CentOS 5.9, using VMWare Server Console. OS booted from CentOS plus  kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For CentOS 5.9, jfsutils is available in the centosplus repo so you need to make sure that repo is enabled.  Alternatively, you should be able to run `yum --enablerepo=centosplus install jfsutils`

Comment: Do I still need to use like that even if I boot from CentOS plus kernel?

Comment: If you have an existing jfs filesystem, I don't think you need it.  It'd still be a good idea since jfsutils provides the fsck command for jfs.  If you do not have an existing jfs filesystem, you'll need jfsutils because it provides mkfs.jfs.